# How to load Lemonbar on BSPWM?

Tags: window-manager, taskbar

I've made a simple script to load Lemonbar:

```
echo "testing" | lemonbar -p
```

I can run it fine:

```
./launch.sh &
```

But if I add that line to my `bspwmrc`, it will have no effect on startup. I always need to launch the bar manually. Is it not possible to launch Lemonbar inside bspwmrc?

Answer (score 0):

Put it at the end of your *bspwmrc* like this one.

[My lemonbar loading from bspwmrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02u13.png)